# JavaScript: How follow the position of an element inside multiple scrollable containers?

Tags: javascript

i want follow the position of an element inside the DOM and changing the position of other element like a "magnetic effect".

```js
var follower = document.getElementById('follower');
var target = document.getElementById('target');
var btn = document.getElementById('btn');


function updatePosition(){

  follower.style.position = 'fixed';
  follower.style.boxShadow = '10px 10px 15px -10px rgba(0,0,0,0.75)';

  var cellRect = target.getBoundingClientRect();
  follower.style.left = `${cellRect.left}px`;
  follower.style.top = `${cellRect.bottom + 5}px`;
  follower.style.width = `${cellRect.width}px`;
}

function startFollowing(){
  setInterval(() => {
        updatePosition();
  }, 100);
  updatePosition();
}


startFollowing();
```

```css
#follower, #target {
  padding: 10px 10px 10px 10px;
  color: white;
  font-weight: bold;
  width: 100px;
}

#follower {
  background: red;
}

#target {
  background: green;
}
```

```html
<div style="max-height: 500px; overflow: auto">
  <br>scroll me<br>scroll me<br>scroll me<br>scroll me<br>scroll me<br>scroll me<br>scroll me<br>scroll me<br>
  <br>scroll me<br>scroll me<br>scroll me<br>scroll me<br>scroll me<br>scroll me<br>scroll me<br>scroll me<br>
    <div style="max-height: 250px; overflow: auto">
    <br>scroll me<br>scroll me<br>scroll me<br>scroll me<br>scroll me<br>scroll me<br>scroll me<br>scroll me<br>
      <br>scroll me<br>scroll me<br>scroll me<br>scroll me<br>scroll me<br>scroll me<br>scroll me<br>scroll me<br>
      <div id="target">I'm the target</div>
      <br>scroll me<br>scroll me<br>scroll me<br>scroll me<br>scroll me<br>scroll me<br>scroll me<br>scroll me<br>
      <br>scroll me<br>scroll me<br>scroll me<br>scroll me<br>scroll me<br>scroll me<br>scroll me<br>scroll me<br>
    </div>
  <br>scroll me<br>scroll me<br>scroll me<br>scroll me<br>scroll me<br>scroll me<br>scroll me<br>scroll me<br>
  <br>scroll me<br>scroll me<br>scroll me<br>scroll me<br>scroll me<br>scroll me<br>scroll me<br>scroll me<br>
</div>


<br><br>


<div id="follower">I'm the follower</div>
```

The problem is var `target.getBoundingClientRect()` don't return the target position on element scroll.

How follow the position of an element inside multiple scrollable containers?

Side note: I can't change the "follower" container...

Comment: Maybe use `requestAnimationFrame()` instead of `setInterval()`.

Answer (score 1):

So you want to hide the follower, when the target isn't visible anymore?
Just check if the target is in the current viewport and hide/show the follower depending on the results like this.

```
var follower = document.getElementById('follower');
var target = document.getElementById('target');
var btn = document.getElementById('btn');


function updatePosition(){

  follower.style.position = 'fixed';
  follower.style.boxShadow = '10px 10px 15px -10px rgba(0,0,0,0.75)';

  var cellRect = target.getBoundingClientRect();
  follower.style.left = `${cellRect.left}px`;
  follower.style.top = `${cellRect.bottom + 5}px`;
  follower.style.width = `${cellRect.width}px`;
  if(isInViewport(target)){
    follower.style.display = 'block';  
  }else{
    follower.style.display = 'none';  
  }
}

function isInViewport(elem) {
    var bounding = elem.getBoundingClientRect();
    return (
        bounding.top >= 0 &&
        bounding.left >= 0 &&
        bounding.bottom <= (window.innerHeight || document.documentElement.clientHeight) &&
        bounding.right <= (window.innerWidth || document.documentElement.clientWidth)
    );
};

function startFollowing(){
  setInterval(() => {
        updatePosition();
  }, 100);
  updatePosition();
}


startFollowing();
```

https://gomakethings.com/how-to-test-if-an-element-is-in-the-viewport-with-vanilla-javascript/

Comment: Thanks, but isn't perfect... https://stackblitz.com/edit/typescript-xnv5jv?file=index.ts the problem is to track multiple scollable containers

Comment: ah i see, using jquery this would be super easy `$(target).is(':visible')`